# How to open iOS app when Push Notification custom button clicked?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I added some button into the iOS Push notification, e.g., I customized the Push Notification Banner/Alerts with some custom buttons, which I'd like to open the app.

Currently when I click the Banner/"Open" button of Alert dialog, the app runs successfully.

I want to add opening app event programmatically.

PS. It's about the interactive Push Notification. And on my research there isn't answer relevant to this question.

Comment: Are you talking about interactive notifications in iOS 8?

Comment: Yes, interactive notification issue. I can handle the event when the custom button clicked. What I want is to open the app. As you may know there's "Open" button in Notification Alerts which opens the app.

Comment: I'm sure that this question is not duplicated. It seems like you don't know what the problem is, Kheldar.

Comment: You can set the action button mode (setActivationMode)  to UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground .

Comment: UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action2;
            action2 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
            [action2 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground];
            [action2 setTitle:@"Close"];
            [action2 setIdentifier:NotificationActionTwoIdent];
            [action2 setDestructive:NO];
            [action2 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

Comment: @Hiroto did you got solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Correction as Sudhan points out:

The `UIUserNotificationAction` objects that you are going to add to your `UIUserNotificationCategory` have a method `activationMode`, it can take constant `UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground`

```
yourNotifificationAction.activationMode=UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground
```

When the user presses the action button, app will launch in foreground and call this method on the `appDelegate`:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
```

Comment: and the above won't work as this is to open application from other application.Just try this  ( [action1 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground]; ), i think you used up Activation Mode Background @Hiroto

Comment: @Anny please upvote if you found this answer helpful.